# When does the derivative of this function vanish?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Start by letting $F \subseteq [0,1]$ be a fat Cantor set with $m(P) > 0$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure. Define $E = [0,1]\setminus F$. Consider function $$f(x) = \int_0^x \mathbb{1}_E(t) \, dt,$$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $\mathbb{1}_E$ is the indicator of the set $E$. Now it is straightforward to show that $f$ is absolutely continuous and monotone increasing (strictly in fact), actually it only depends on the fact that $E$ has finite measure. I want to study where this function has its derivative equal to $0$. However, I seem to get stuck if I just use the formal definition of the derivative, as it tells me nothing about what points make this true. My idea was to maybe use Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem or Density Theorem. Now after playing with these ideas I conclude that $x \in E$ then $x$ is a Lebesgue point. However, I cannot proceed after this.

Can someone kindly provide some help?

Krull.

Edit: After playing some more with the equation this is what I came up with
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h} \mathbb{1}_E dt = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2h} \int_{E \cap [x-h,x+h]} dt \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{m(E \cap [x-h,x+h])}{2h}  = 0
\end{align}$$ for a.e. $x \in F$. We can conclude that $f'(x) = 0$ on a.e. $x \in F$.

Is the reasoning above correct? Also, it seems the proof does not even rely on the sets $F$ and $E$ unless I am missing something ..

Comment: Each point in $F$ is in either the upper part or the lower part, and then in the upper or lower part of that part, and then in the upper or lower part of that part of that part, and so on, so each point in $F$ as a corresponding sequence that looks like this: $ULLUUULULLU\ldots\,.$  Perhaps there are just three kinds of points in the domain to consider: $(1)$ points in $[0,1]\smallsetminus F$ (I think you already done that); $(2)$ points in $F$ for which the sequence of $U$s and $L$s contains only $U$s or only $L$s after some point; and $(3)$ other points in $F. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy - Thank you for your comment it was very insightful. I think I was able to solve this by looking at $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (f(x+h)-f(x-h))/h$. After simplification we get that this is simply $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} m(E \cap [x-h,x+h])/h$ and this is $0$ for a.e. $x \in F$.

Comment: Typo above: $\quad\uparrow\quad$ "I think you've already done that" $\qquad$